# YouTube Data API channels list returning no results for valid Channel ID

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm attempting to access https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC7LoiySz7-FcGgZCKBq_2vQ via the YouTube Data API v3 however am not able to load channel by id:

```
https://content.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&id=UC7LoiySz7-FcGgZCKBq_2vQ&key=<omitted>
{
  "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
  "etag": "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/Rk41fm-2TD0VG1yv0-bkUvcBi9s\"",
    "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 0,
    "resultsPerPage": 0
  },
  "items": []
}
```

other channels that this same error occurs for:
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCzwNZaQ2qyZw0n3xOSNoXaQ
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC0iFwqagVPP6pXiDwYU170g

Answer (score 0):

Your channels are of type hidden. This is the expected outcome. Unhide it and work your way from there.

[Delete or hide your YouTube channel](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/55759?hl=en):

> You can hide content from your YouTube channel and choose to re-enable
>   it later. When you hide content, your channel name, videos, likes,
>   subscriptions, and subscribers will be made private.
>
> All your comments and replies will be permanently deleted. Your
>   account data on other Google properties will not be removed.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @noogui.  A "hidden" channel would help explain why there doesn't appear to be any content on the channels linked above.  Just to understand better, is it possible for someone to determine that the channel is hidden?  The links are still loadable in a browser with a presumed channel id in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

One more time YouTube Data API v3 doesn't provide a basic feature.

I recommend you to try out my [open-source](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/commit/32782dda10297ec080b25872b8e260566ba66c15#diff-651cb6f72df27343556303c689f24c67c4cb90e2881f464e665c151429551dacR75-R85) [YouTube operational API](https://yt.lemnoslife.com). Indeed by fetching https://yt.lemnoslife.com/channels?part=status&id=CHANNEL_ID, you will get the YouTube channel status message you are looking for in `item["status"]`.

For instance with this channel id [`UC7LoiySz7-FcGgZCKBq_2vQ`](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC7LoiySz7-FcGgZCKBq_2vQ) you would get:

```json
{
    "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
    "etag": "NotImplemented",
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "youtube#channel",
            "etag": "NotImplemented",
            "id": "UC7LoiySz7-FcGgZCKBq_2vQ",
            "status": "This channel is not available."
        }
    ]
}
```

For a suspended YouTube channel such as [`UCF_UozwQBJY4WHZ7yilYkjA`](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCF_UozwQBJY4WHZ7yilYkjA), you would get for `status`: `"This account has been terminated due to multiple or severe violations of YouTube's policy on nudity or sexual content."`.

For a normal channel, such as [`UC4QobU6STFB0P71PMvOGN5A`](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC4QobU6STFB0P71PMvOGN5A), you would get for `status`: `null`.